# change ActionBar layout when click on button

Tags: java, android-actionbar

I want to change my actionbar for an actionbar with custom layout when i click on a button.

I don't have found solution.

I tried

```
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
```

but it does not work.

Thx for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
LayoutInflater inflater = 
              (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);
getActionBar().setCustomView(view);
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: It progress :p My custom bar appears but the old is still here ^^ Have you got some idea ?

Comment: `getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

Comment: Ok thx it works. 
Just one last question -> How can i disable item (button) from my old actionbar ? I tried setVisible(false) on a class var but it seems not working

Comment: I think you should delete `onCreateOptionsMenu` method from your activity class.